# Create registration page in 3 tier

Tags: .net, 3-tier

I am new to .net technology.I am doing a project in .net.
I want to create registration form in 3 tier.How to create this one.Please anyone guide me please...Give me one example.

Answer (score 0):

Look here for some help on your question

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/05/introduction-to-3-tier-architecture-in_17.html

Comment: But in that application we don't have back end..That is stored procedures. How to define stored procedure for that solution?